# Using contains in scala - exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am encountering this error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;`

whenever I try to use "contains" to find if a string is inside an array. Is there a more appropriate way of doing this?  Or, am I doing something wrong? (I am fairly new to Scala)

Here is the code:

```
val matches = Set[JSONObject]()
val config = new SparkConf()
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "SparkExample", config)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val ebay = sqlContext.read.json("/Users/thomassquires/Downloads/products.json")
val catalogue = sqlContext.read.json("/Users/thomassquires/Documents/catalogue2.json")

val eins = ebay.map(item => (item.getAs[String]("ID"), Option(item.getAs[Set[Row]]("itemSpecifics"))))
  .filter(item => item._2.isDefined)
  .map(item => (item._1 , item._2.get.find(x => x.getAs[String]("k") == "EAN")))
  .filter(x => x._2.isDefined)
  .map(x => (x._1, x._2.get.getAs[String]("v")))
  .collect()

    def catEins =  catalogue.map(r => (r.getAs[String]("_id"), Option(r.getAs[Array[String]]("item_model_number")))).filter(r => r._2.isDefined).map(r => (r._1, r._2.get)).collect()

  def matched = for(ein <- eins) yield (ein._1, catEins.filter(z => z._2.contains(ein._2)))
```

The exception occurs on the last line. I have tried a few different variants.

My data structure is one `List[Tuple2[String, String]]` and one `List[Tuple2[String, Array[String]]]` . I need to find the zero or more matches from the second list that contain the string.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are collecting and then filtering? Because ideally you should always collect your end result.

Comment: Mainly to pin down the error. Since its lazy i only get the error on collect. I wanted to rule out errors on the first two sets

Comment: Try annotating types of all vals, it will also help others to reason about your code. Btw why `matched` and `catEins` are `def`s instead of `val`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short (there is still part that eludes me here*) you're using wrong types. `getAs` is implemented as `fieldIndex` (`String => Int`) followed by `get` (`Int => Any`) followed by `asInstanceOf`.

Since Spark doesn't use `Arrays` nor `Sets` but `WrappedArray` to store `array` column data, calls like `getAs[Array[String]]` or `getAs[Set[Row]]` are not valid. If you want specific types you should use either `getAs[Seq[T]]` or `getAsSeq[T]` and convert your data to desired type with `toSet` / `toArray`.

---

* See [Why wrapping a generic method call with Option defers ClassCastException?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36138540/1560062)