# Why wrapping a generic method call with Option defers ClassCastException?

Tags: scala, generics, classcastexception, scala-option, scala-generics

Lets say I have an array like this*:

```
val foo: Any = 1 : Int
Option(foo.asInstanceOf[String])
```

which fails for obvious reason:

```
// java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to 
// java.lang.String
// ... 48 elided
```

Next lets consider a following class:

```
case class DummyRow() {
  val foo: Any = 1 : Int
  def getAs[T] = foo.asInstanceOf[T]
  def getAsOption[T] = Option(foo.asInstanceOf[T])
}
```

As far as I can tell `getAs` should behave the same way as the previous `apply` followed by `asInstanceOf`.

Surprisingly it is not the case. When called alone it throws an exception:

```
DummyRow().getAs[String]
// java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to 
// java.lang.String
// ... 48 elided
```

but when wrapped with `Option` succeeds:

```
val stringOption = Option(DummyRow().getAs[String])
// Option[String] = Some(1)

DummyRow().getAsOption[String]
// Option[String] = Some(1)
```

and fails only when I try to access wrapped value:

```
stringOption.get
// java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to 
// java.lang.String
// ... 48 elided
```

So what happens here? It seems to be limited `ClassCastException` so I guess it is related to some ugly thing like type erasure.

---

* `Any` and `asInstanceOf` are there to mimic a behavior of the 3rd party code so please lets not dwell on that.

** Tested in Scala 2.10.5, 2.11.7

*** If you're interested in the context you can take a look at [Using contains in scala - exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36134429/1560062)

**** Other relevant questions linked in the comments:

- [Why does `.asInstanceOf` sometimes throw, and sometimes not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204473/why-does-asinstanceof-sometimes-throw-and-sometimes-not),
- [Why asInstanceOf doesn't throw a ClassCastException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089390/why-asinstanceof-doesnt-throw-a-classcastexception/26089466#26089466)

Comment: This confused me too earlier. 
Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204473/why-does-asinstanceof-sometimes-throw-and-sometimes-not 
It is not exactly the same question as yours, but the answer applies to your case as well.

Comment: OK, this is confusing. I'll need some time to wrap my head around it. Thanks for pointing this out @Dima

Comment: Could be related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089390/why-asinstanceof-doesnt-throw-a-classcastexception/26089466#26089466) (although it's on lists, but probably applies to every complex type `F[_]`).

Comment: @EndeNeu I actually started with a sequence and reduced this to the provided example later. It looks like [almendar is onto something](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36139276/1560062) here with pointing out that it is related to generics.

Comment: Read your compiler warnings.

Comment: @ChrisMartin This always a good advice but compiler seems to perfectly happy about it. Do you have any particular options in mind?

Comment: @zero323 My mistake, sorry for commenting without testing. I thought `.asInstanceOf[T]` was an unchecked cast due to partial erasure, but on second look I see it isn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is a simplified version of your problem with an additional case for `Any`

```
def getAs[T] = (1:Int).asInstanceOf[T]

//blows up
getAs[String]

//blows up
def p(s:String): Unit = {}
p(getAs[String])

//works
def p[T](s:T): Unit = {}
p(getAs[String])

//works
def p(s:Any): Unit = {}
p(getAs[String])
```

Because you create a method with a generic parameter, the runtime doesn't need to "touch" the value because it does not care. Generic will be treated as `Any`/`Object` at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following (slightly edited for reading purposes) REPL session:

```
scala> class Foo(foo: Any) {
     | def getAs[T] = foo.asInstanceOf[T]
     | def getAsString = foo.asInstanceOf[String]
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> :javap Foo
  Size 815 bytes
  MD5 checksum 6d77ff638c5719ca1cf996be4dbead62
  Compiled from "<console>"
public class Foo
{
  public <T extends java/lang/Object> T getAs();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0       
         1: getfield      #11                 // Field foo:Ljava/lang/Object;
         4: areturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       5     0  this   LFoo;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 12: 0
    Signature: #35                          // <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>()TT;

  public java.lang.String getAsString();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0       
         1: getfield      #11                 // Field foo:Ljava/lang/Object;
         4: checkcast     #17                 // class java/lang/String
         7: areturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       8     0  this   LFoo;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 13: 0
}
```

You can see in the bytecode of `getAsString` that a `checkcast` instruction is executed when casting to a `String`. On the other hand in `getAs[T]` no such instruction gets executed even though there is a cast in the code. The reason for that is that `T` gets erased to `Any` at runtime, so that would simply become a cast to `Any` (which would never fail). So casting to a type parameter is only necessary for the compiler's sake, not the JVM's. So no casting has to happen when you wrap that call in `Option` which is generic too. It's only when you want to get the value out of the `Option` and treat it as a `String` that a cast is executed and an exception is thrown.

```
scala> class Bar() {
     | def getString: String = new Foo(3).getAs[String]
     | def get[T]: T = new Foo(3).getAs[T]
     | }
defined class Bar

scala> :javap Bar
  Size 1005 bytes
  MD5 checksum 4b7bee878db4235ca9c011c6f168b4c9
  Compiled from "<console>"
public class Bar
{
  public java.lang.String getString();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: new           #9                  // class Foo
         3: dup           
         4: iconst_3      
         5: invokestatic  #15                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
         8: invokespecial #19                 // Method Foo."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        11: invokevirtual #23                 // Method Foo.getAs:()Ljava/lang/Object;
        14: checkcast     #25                 // class java/lang/String
        17: areturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0      18     0  this   LBar;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 13: 0

  public <T extends java/lang/Object> T get();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: new           #9                  // class Foo
         3: dup           
         4: iconst_3      
         5: invokestatic  #15                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
         8: invokespecial #19                 // Method Foo."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        11: invokevirtual #23                 // Method Foo.getAs:()Ljava/lang/Object;
        14: areturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0      15     0  this   LBar;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 14: 0
    Signature: #51                          // <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>()TT;
}
```

As you can see `checkcast` is executed after `getAs` instead of during, and only in a non-generic context.