# Scala unexplainable program behavior

Tags: scala, casting, type-inference, type-erasure

For the following code:

```
object Test {

  class MapOps(map: Map[String, Any]) {
    def getValue[T](name: String): Option[T] = {
      map.get(name).map{_.asInstanceOf[T]}
    }
  }

  implicit def toMapOps(map: Map[String, Any]): MapOps = new MapOps(map)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val m: Map[String, Any] = Map("1" -> 1, "2" -> "two")

    val a = m.getValue[Int]("2").get.toString
    println(s"1: $a")

    val b = m.getValue[Int]("2").get
    println(s"2: $b")
  }
}
```

`val a` is computed without exception and the console prints `1: two`,
but when computing `val b`, the `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` is thrown.

Besides, if I execute

```
val c = m.getValue[Int]("2").get.getClass.toString
println(s"1: $c")
```

The console prints "int".

Can someone explain why this code behaves like this?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138540/why-wrapping-a-generic-method-call-with-option-defers-classcastexception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is certainly odd.

If you look at the following statement in the *Scala REPL*:

```
scala> val x = m.getValue[Int]("2")
x: Option[Int] = Some(two)
```

What I think is happening is this: the `asInstanceOf[T]` statement is simply flagging to the compiler that the result should be an `Int`, but no cast is required, because the object is still just referenced via a pointer. (And `Int` values are boxed inside of an `Option`/`Some`) `.toString` works because every object has a `.toString` method, which just operates on the value "two" to yield "two". However, when you attempt to assign the result to an `Int` variable, the compiler attempts to unbox the stored integer, and the result is a cast exception, because the value is a `String` and not a boxed `Int`.

Let's verify this step-by-step in the *REPL*:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> class MapOps(map: Map[String, Any]) {
     |     def getValue[T](name: String): Option[T] = {
     |       map.get(name).map{_.asInstanceOf[T]}
     |     }
     |   }
defined class MapOps

scala> import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.language.implicitConversions

scala> implicit def toMapOps(map: Map[String, Any]): MapOps = new MapOps(map)
toMapOps: (map: Map[String,Any])MapOps

scala> val a = m.getValue[Int]("2").get.toString
a: String = two

scala> println(s"1: $a")
1: two
```

So far so good. Note that no exceptions have been thrown so far, even though we have already used `.asInstanceOf[T]` and used `get` on the resulting value. What's significant is that we haven't attempted to do anything with the result of the `get` call (nominally a boxed `Int` that is actually the `String` value "two") except to invoke it's `toString` method. That works, because `String` values have `toString` methods.

Now let's perform the assignment to an `Int` variable:

```
scala> val b = m.getValue[Int]("2").get
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
  at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:101)
  ... 29 elided
```

*Now* we get the exception! Note also the function in the stack trace that caused it: `unboxToInt` - it's clearly trying to convert the value stored in the `Some` to an `Int` and it fails because it's not a boxed `Int` but a `String.`

A big part of the problem is *type erasure*. Don't forget that a `Some(Banana)` and a `Some(Bicycle)` are - at runtime - both just `Some` instances with a pointer to some object. `.asInstanceOf[T]` cannot verify the type, because that information has been erased. However, the compiler is able to track what the type should be based upon what you've told it, but it can only detect the error when its assumptions are proven wrong.

Finally, with regard to the `getClass` call on the result. This is a bit of compiler sleight-of-hand. It's not actually calling a `getClass` function on the object, but - because it thinks it's dealing with an `Int`, which is a primitive - it simply substitutes an `int` class instance.

```
scala> m.getValue[Int]("2").get.getClass
res0: Class[Int] = int
```

To verify that the object actually is a `String`, you can cast it to an `Any` as follows:

```
scala> m.getValue[Int]("2").get.asInstanceOf[Any].getClass
res1: Class[_] = class java.lang.String
```

Further verification about the return value of `get` follows; note the lack of an exception when we assign the result of this method to a variable of type `Any` (so no casting is necessary), the fact that the valid `Int` with key "1" is actually stored under `Any` as a boxed `Int` (`java.lang.Integer`), and that this latter value can be successfully unboxed to a regular `Int` primitive:

```
scala> val x: Any = m.getValue[Int]("2").get
x: Any = two

scala> x.getClass
res2: Class[_] = class java.lang.String

scala> val y: Any = m.getValue[Int]("1").get
y: Any = 1

scala> y.getClass
res3: Class[_] = class java.lang.Integer

scala> val z = m.getValue[Int]("1").get
z: Int = 1

scala> z.getClass
res4: Class[Int] = int
```

Comment: Doesn't seem accurate, read the question linked in comment below the question

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the error in a different context. I tried `val c: Any = "two"; Some(c).map(_.asInstanceOf[Int].toString)` and I still get the invalid cast exception. So the option boxing is not enough.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I did read the question you linked to. What is not accurate about my answer?

Comment: Running ` println(m.getValue[Int]("2").map(_.getClass.getName))` after printing `a` still throws the exception.

Comment: @eje211 That's a different problem.

Comment: This explanation makes sense. Thanks @MikeAllen

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the last part of [eje211's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47021074/3851755).

You told the compiler that a `String` was an `Int`, and now you're looking for a sensible explanation of the resulting behavior.  That's understandable, but it's not really useful.  Once you tell the compiler a lie, all bets are off.  You can spend time investigating exactly when and where the compiler inserts checks that happen to discover your deceit, but your time would probably be better spent writing code that doesn't cause you to lie.

As the earlier answer pointed out, you can do that (avoid accidental lying) by using pattern matching.  You'll need a `ClassTag` to make pattern matching work in cases like the above, but the end result will be code that is type-safe and correct.

Answer (score -1):

It's an `Int` because you request an `Int` on this line :

```
val b = m.getValue[Int]("2").get
```

This calls this method:

```
def getValue[T](name: String): Option[T] = {
  map.get(name).map{_.asInstanceOf[T]}
}
```

and applies it this way:

```
def getValue[Int](name: String): Option[Int] = {
  map.get(name).map{_.asInstanceOf[Int]}
}
```

So if you ask for an `Int`, you get an `Int`.

In the case of `"two"`, this is what happens in that case:

```
"two".asInstanceOf[Int]
```

That's what throws your exception.

A `String` is not an Int. You can't cast it that way. You can cast it *this* way:

```
"2".toInt
```

But that's different.

In general, using `asInstanceOf[]` is dangerous. Try pattern matching instead. If you *must* use, it's up you to make sure that the casts you attempt are valid. You're basically telling the compiler to bypass its own type-checks, particularly when you cast from `Any`.

It works when you add `.toString` because then, you change the type back to String, which is what it really was in the first place. The lie of what type the data was is corrected.

Comment: If you ask for an `Int` but you have a String, you get a runtime exception, not an `Int`

Comment: True. I found where the error occurs. Not what causes it.

Comment: The value of  `m.getValue[Int]("2").get.toString` is "two", but the value of `m.getValue[Int]("2").get` is an exception because "two" cannot be cast to an `Int`. So how come adding `.toString` works? Also, `m.getValue[Int]("2")` is returned as `Some("two")`.

Comment: The wrong cast is the error. Due to the generic parameter it's deferred until the get is invoked

Comment: @GabrielePetronella That's not quite true. `get` is invoked in the statement that works, but no exception is thrown. Why? It's only when the result of `get` is assigned to the `Int` variable, `b` - and so needs to, so far as the compiler can tell, unbox a boxed `Int`, that a cast exception results.

Comment: @eje211 It's not the `.asInstanceOf[T]` that is throwing the exception, though. If that was the case, it would happen in _both_ calls to `getValue` - but it only happens in the second one. The exception is only thrown when the attempt is made to store the result (which the compiler has been told is a boxed `Int`) to an `Int` - and fails because it has a reference to a `String` instead.